Help in identifying an abnormal PCB found suspiciously
This is an odd PCB I found a while ago on the bedroom floor of my apartment next to my bed where my dongle for extra USB-3 ports was hanging off the bed. I have no relationship to this board, it's not mine, and it's not from something I had taken apart.
My landlord had illegal cameras for the longest time, and I believe this may be a spy device. I'm nervous as there is most likely more and I've been inexplicably poisoned 4x since December, 1st with drugs, then medications and alcohol, I don't drink nor drug so shouldn't be coming up in my urine at hospital.  I'm extremely scared and if this is a camera-type or spy device it's all I need to save my life — I have some details and readings below. I beg you, please help me!
I need help in identifying what this device would be used for with the specific components it's composed of. I took some readings of parts of concern and the most interesting is Figure A on Side B, what I believe to be an Infra-Red Diode, quite possibly an imaging one, I've never seen a diode like this one before. I was able to measure the Diode twice (with M-Tester, it's a knock-off of the nice one, but it works just as good) and these were the readings I got, these were super hard to get as this device is rather compact.
So for Figure A, marked “D1” on the board, I got the following readings:
diode: Ir=10μa Uf=795  |  diode Ir=5.3μav Uf=792 c=2.86nf
Yes they do differ a bit, but like I said it was hard to get this one. From what I've read this falls within the range of an infra-red diode, I could be wrong, but that's what I've come to.
Another suspicious part is the 2 LEDs on Side A (Figure B).  I've never seen 4 contact point LEDs nor LEDs that look like this one, and I've seen a lot of LEDs in my life. When tested, they flash & light up blue. I also ran the tester on them and got the following results:
Figure B marked “LED1” & “LED2” on the board, I took two readings then the third provided a different answer, I believe it tested them together:
Read 1: diode Ir=9.5μa Uf=3.39V
Read 2: diode Ir=6.1ua uf=646mv c= too fast to capture number
Read 3: LED1/LED2: Uf=3.33v Uf=2.327v  [1,2,1 (Polarity) aka: + - +]
I'm not wholly familiar with these sort of values, I know a lot but i'm still learning and that's why I'm begging for help. The other items on the board are pretty self explanatory in the image but I will write them out here regardless.
Side A has 3x SMD Resistors marked “R3” with “910”; “R4” with “820” and “R5” with another “820” but flipped in orientation.
Side A also has a marking “C1” with what I believe to be a teeny SMD-type capacitor, I couldn't get a reading on it, too small. There is also “C2” with just a pad.
Another point of interest is Figure E with the placement of “J1” without any jumpers, though there are tiny holes, so maybe during validation there was one?  Lastly, about side A, is there is a white box-like marking at the bottom, I wonder what that represents.
Side B, is ironically the more interesting side in my opinion, we have that main feature Diode (Figure A) mentioned above but also much more.
As you can see in the picture, there is another even smaller resistor marked “R1” with no value on it and too small to get a read on.
A button switch marked “S1” sits at the “top” of the device but I don't know which way is really top lol (im talking about in image) the marking “S1” is blocked a bit by flash-glare but indicated in gray).
Next to it is that diode “D1” (Figure A).  Oddly, there is no “R2” resistor on this device just 1,3,4,5... below/above “R1” is a microcontroller with 8 pins and unmarked outside the U1 placed next to it, Pin 1 is notated by a drop of white paint and on the IC itself as per normal with a dot built in, which I have marked as Figure D.
Probably the most eerie part of this device is Figure B, the 4x pads that just about surmounts to a Universal Serial Bus (USB) connector in size and shape and was found next to my USB dongle like it fell out or something..
Oddly, with two holes on the outer pads. I decided to test the device as a whole using these outer pads, and got the following reading. I don't know if it's for the IC or device, but the reading was: 23nAb uf=696mV 96.5nF.

Again I'm just learning these values, so I'm unsure if they can provide enough insight to this device's purpose, but ultimately it's a small device that has very few components, but good ones at that are peculiar as well.
If you want follow-up readings, please ask if you think it'll help you understand the device, I can try testing the things I didn't again as well, if needed.  Please someone help me with this, I'll spare the long story but my life literally rides on figuring out if this is a device meant for malicious purposes or not, if it is, I can press charges on my creepy (and murderous) landlord. I hope someone can help identify this, I've scoward the web looking for someone with a similar matching device and have found no other images of it other than mine.
I will be eternally grateful to anyone who can help with this, I may even be able to reward the person with a gift depending on what it is. A lot rides on figuring this out and quickly, as I'm in severe danger, more so if that is a spy device.


That's a generic USB mood light or basically a flashlight. For illumination. With RGB LEDs. Button to select modes and colours. It has no USB data connections, just power. That is not a least bit suspicious. Please get professional help for your other issues.

sounds like you may be suffering from dissociative identity disorder, also known as split personality... please talk to your doctor

@jsotola, it seems that you hit the right note, the person need a help. IMHO, it's rather paranoid personality disorder. Unfortunately, I don't suppose he'll follow your advice — such people feels themselves OK. But maybe you're the first person who said it to him, and it's good. (See the 2nd paragraph in his profile.)

@MarianD the statement about drugs and alcohol makes me think that the OP is doing things without being aware of doing them and that the creepy landlord is actually themselves

@jsotola, your explanation is highly likely correct. You have my admiration.

As surmised in the comments already, this is most likely a cheap "mood light" USB device, which has two RGB LEDs for increased brightness, and a button to change the mode / color...
If you don't like it or want it around, then give it away or put it in the bin.
To address your concerns about what this device is, the following points are well educated but not guaranteed to be correct.

"Figure B" looks like a cheap "PCB-only" variant of a USB A plug, and is likely related to the J1 designator on Side A. The D+ and D- pads don't appear to be connected - if so, it's using USB for power only.
I'd guess that LED1 and LED2 are common anode RGB LEDs - connected to the 5v USB supply on one side, and then sharing current limiting resistors for each color channel (R3, R4, R5 are connected to the same pins of both LEDs)
"Figure A" (the "Diode of Interest") may just be an indication LED, likely D1. There is no way it's "quite possibly an imaging one".
U1 is likely some cheap microcontroller or dedicated "RGB controller" IC - it doesn't appear to be connected to the USB data signals. I'd guess the 8 pins are likely connected to: VCC, 0v, Red, Green, Blue, Button, Indicator LED, N/C (not in that order)
S1 is a button, nothing more - given the lack of USB connection, it's likely used to change the mode or color selected
There are no microphones, cameras, sensors, energy storage, or obvious antennas

